# Why do game developers ask for so much money for their games?

Tags: game-industry, costs

For many years now the cost of video games has been bothering me. I’ll admit. I’ve only been playing videos games since the NES days right up to the PlayStation 2, after that I pretty much switched off. So I missed about 3 generations of consoles. But during my active days you brought a game and everything was included and you simple had to play the game long enough to unlock additional content, for free! I’ve been reading and watching the disastrous launch of Gran Turismo 7 and the constant nonstop backlash it’s receiving for its micro transaction system.

At the moment I’m a solo game developer and I will likely need hire people from other areas such as art and music to help me in developing my title. I can’t hand on heart ask my potential future players to cough up £70 for the base game and then additional money for DLC, micro transactions, in app purchases or whatever you want to call it. I feel it’s plan wrong. And don’t get me started on NFTs like what Konami and others have done!

My question is this. How comes other forms of entertainment like buying the latest blockbuster movie is many times cheaper and would cost roughly the same or even more to make. How do these developers justify asking for so much money, including asking players for more money even after the game has been sold (e.g. for minor extra content like a different re-skin)?

Update
Do you think these kind of business practices could end up permanently harming the gaming industry?

Also, as I’m a sole game developer. I have to think about every single aspect of my titles development not just the coding side of things, but also the time and money from my personal savings I see myself having to pump into my project. I have come across others with the same concerns. So I thinks it’s a very valid question as people like me are not paid by the hour and we don’t have the luxury of focusing entirely on the code/tech side of game dev and so I have to worry about my future players/customers (if any) views and concerns they have due to being treated like a cash cow.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about game development.

Comment: I agree it sounds like a rant. However, "why do I need to extract that much money from my player base" appers to be about the game industry.

Comment: As I said clearly, I haven’t “played” which by extension means I haven’t brought a game since the PS2 days. So 20 years ago, so I can’t possibly be ranting as I’m not a game consumer. I’m creating my own title as a solely developer and I want to get an understanding of the backlash towards studios for asking customers to folk out more money for content which should be included in the finished product. I don’t won’t to either a) treat my customers as cash cows and b) waste time in implementing DLC methods in my title only to then receive the same backlash and have to spend time to remove it.

Comment: Okay, so is your question actually about "what is the effect of adding micro-transactions and pay-for-DLCs on customers perception", or about "why have game companies developed so many revenue techniques"? I understand you're not ranting, however if you formulate the question in such a way it reads from a "displeased" "player" point of view, it might be interpreted as such.

Comment: If you think you can reword the question to make it clearer, and answerable in an objective manner, we'll be happy to reopen it.

Comment: FWIW, someone presented a [webinar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVpmwI3AaSE) some time ago about how you can approach monetizing your game, maybe that could be of interest to you. _"I don’t won’t_ (sic) _to [...] treat my customers as cash cows [...]"_ Keep in mind that at the end of the day, you need the money in your pocket. If you want to sell your game upfront and not ask for more money, that's fine, just make sure your business model can sustain this. Estimate realistically upfront how much you can sell your game for and how many copies you'll sell, then do the math; is it viable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At the moment I’m a solo game developer and will likely hire people from other areas to me in developing my title

So I will turn this into actual advice. But not advice on what to say to justify high prices.

---

### Prices do not reflect costs

The relation between the production cost and the selling price is not direct. Since games inmaterial - and even more so with digital distribution - you can sell an unbounded number of licenses.

But don't forget that once a person bought license to a game they are unlikely to buy another. Also, people buy new games only ever so often.

So the question is: How elastic is the market? How much does it respond to price incentives? If people will buy pretty much the same number of licenses if you raise or lower the price, you have the incentive to sell as expensive as they can get away with it.

*However, you don't have to do what the big studios do with their prices.*

Adjusting your prices is a tacit negotiation with everybody. Thus, it is a good idea to study the market to see what people would find to be a reasonable price. And for a gut check, you can ask yourself if you would be willing to pay for it if it was made by somebody else.

---

### Game studio finances

I presume you have a budget for the development of your game. It has to pay for equipment, salaries, and so on. But that budget is not infinite, so there will be a date when it runs out. That is your main dead line. You want your game done before you hit it.

If you starting a video game development studio and you hired employees, I hope you don't lay them off after the first release. But having employees around doing nothing isn't good either. So you have incentive to start another project right away. *So you haven't recoup the first investment and you are incurring in a second one.*

*In fact, for management it makes sense to have a couple projects going at the same time, and move people between them<strike>, so they are always stressed</strike>.*

Hopefully income arrives and it is greater than expenses so the studio can stay afloat. Thus, if your games can provide income for a long time, it is better for the finance of the studio. And I remind you that once a person bought license to a game they are unlikely to buy another. So you would want to keep attracting new players.

There is soft cap on the number of player due to the time the game will be in the zeitgeist before fading from relevance behind newer titles. And there is a somewhat harder cap in the the market share of the console/platform. *The market is only so elastic.*

*By the way, keeping servers online also has a cost.*

If only games could produce a secondary revenue stream… Ah.

---

Well, if you consider using micro-transactions, consider also a freemium model. Sadly mobile games have given freemium a bad reputation, and price signals effort put in the product. But freemium is a way for players to pay for the game after they know they enjoy it, not before.

That isn't the only option, of course. In particular for an online game, a subscription model makes sense.

**Whatever you decide for the monetization of your games, I would like to encourage transparency.**

---

It is important to be smart with your budget. In particular consider the scenario where you need to make unexpected changes to your game. If it does not imply to pay for voice actors and motion capture and and so on, then making the changes is easier. Thus, if you intent to have those things, it is a good idea to delay them.

It is a mistake to try to plan it all ahead of time with the intention of getting it right the first time… Because chances are you are not going to, and you will have to make changes. On a similar note, test early. If you test and discover you need to make changes, hopefully it does not mean a big sunk cost.

---

### On selling cosmetics

Selling cosmetics means that what you are selling does not affect game play at all. Cosmetics do not make the game easier.

With this monetization strategy, you do not have the incentive to make the game bad (or impossible, i.e. paywalls) to push player to buy something that makes the game easier (pay to win).

So, I would defend selling skins - in particular in freemium games - as long as the player knows what they are getting, and it is not paired with predatory tactics such as fear of missing out. And don't forget some artist had to make those skins, so they do have a cost.

However, yes, we had ridiculously priced golden mounts and also monocles and other things. Don't do that. Unfair prices are unfair. And it is a good thing that people speak up about bad micro transactions. And you don't want to be on the receiving end of that.

Comment: Hi Theraot, this was a very well thought out opinionated answer. You assumed correctly, I do have a very finite supply of money I can invest into my project. So I think it’s extremely important to ask for other game developers opinions on what seems like an almost around the clock coverage of in game purchases from gaming journalists  and the customers on social media and this topic has gotten me somewhat worried for a while now. I’ve still got at least another year and a half to go before I hope to complete my game development and I will take what you say on board.

Comment: I'd like to note that on Dead by Daylight, we have some cosmetics that are notoriously "Pay to lose" where they make a player in a game that rewards stealth very brightly colored. :D

Answer (score -2):

These are both good and very warranted questions.  It's nothing short of ridiculous paying 70 quid or more for some of the emerging AAA titles.  Micro-transactions behind anything but free-to-play is just as much so.

In response to one of your questions, regarding the cost of films vs games..well, it's complex.  First and foremost, the majority of films will see more puchases/views than than a typical  game will see first-light plays.

Programmers are expensive to hire, particularly if they specialise in something like DirectX. One main reason for the high wages they expect is simply because they're not as common as programmers who specialise in other areas.

So while game development can be expensive, platforms like Steam and GamePass are good choices for distribution.

Comment: I agree, £70 is a high amount to pay, remember the Neo-Geo days. But I do understand why they are priced so. It’s because the console manufactures sells devices at a loss and they need to recoup their losses. Even so, I would still find it very difficult to ask any potential players of mine to pay me more money on top of a “finished” game I’ve sold them. The new Gran Turismo has got my attention because I’m also making a racer. To unlock the games hidden content would either take 10yrs of non-stop play or another £500! I feel very few will meet either condition so I don’t understand the logic.

Answer (score -3):

The video game industry is more cut throat than you think. Everyone wants to be here, and nobody wants to work (human nature.) Studios that get funding by massive producers have no choice but to follow orders/deadlines to the T, or they have to lay off Jimmy who has a wife and two kids.

Blockbuster films are no walk in the park, either, I promise you. When you're selling art, in the form of entertainment, you are a luxury item. You are worthless, in a survival aspect. Pair this with how competitive the video game industry is, only the best survive. For lack of a better 'best' barometer, money usually takes the top priority.

Making video games is a lot more involved than my beloved super mario world days. A super mario world can be pooped out by an amature within days. To pull off some of these modern games.. They can require tons of engineers, all working together in the same codebase, with TIGHT deadlines.

I get it. The games industry sucks right now. All industries have highs and lows. What the players want, is what makes the money. What makes the money, is what comes out.

'Ol Tommy can cry online about those microtransactions all day. But the reason why Farmville runs, is because Tommy stole his mom's credit card to buy those tokens. He's crying because he's grounded.

TL;DR: Don't hate the player, hate the game.
(Your player is your customer, please don't hate them)